# get-adgroup will not accept group distinguished name in a variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

**See here that I can do a get-adgroup by specifying the actual group DN for Identity**

```
PS C:\Users\gdewrell> get-adgroup -Identity "CN=Group_3d2ec95b-5465-4d1e-99cc-fa06ea1190a9,DC=PDINET,DC=COM" -server $DC

DistinguishedName : CN=Group_3d2ec95b-5465-4d1e-99cc-fa06ea1190a9,DC=PDINET,DC=COM
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Universal
Name              : Group_3d2ec95b-5465-4d1e-99cc-fa06ea1190a9
ObjectClass       : group
ObjectGUID        : 2aa8581b-3a60-4e94-bd25-ca0825fd2bb2
SamAccountName    : $G98000-HD196N3A163E
SID               : S-1-5-21-1869882585-404498175-2374520063-8496
```

**Notice that I have a variable called $group.memberof (gotten by get-aduser and the member of parameter) and contains the exact same DN as above.**

```
PS C:\Users\gdewrell> $group.memberof

CN=Group_3d2ec95b-5465-4d1e-99cc-fa06ea1190a9,DC=PDINET,DC=COM
```

**Now if I try to use get-adgroup using the variable I get this error.**

```
PS C:\Users\gdewrell> get-adgroup -Identity $group.memberof -server $DC

Get-ADGroup : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to the type 
'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:23
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I hope the AD Object information you're sharing with us is from a test lab ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`MemberOf` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-memberof) of a given [`ADObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adobject?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) is a *multi-valued attribute* (a [`ADPropertyValueCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adpropertyvaluecollection-1?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) collection to be more specific). This means that even if the `MemberOf` attribute of your group has only one value (a *DistinguishedName*), it is still a collection. See [**User Security Attributes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/security-properties?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for details.

None of the [**Constructors**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adgroup?view=activedirectory-management-10.0#constructors) from the [`ADGroup` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adgroup?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) accept an `ADPropertyValueCollection` as argument hence why you see this error, which is basically PowerShell telling you that it *cannot convert the collection to the type of an `ADGroup`*.

However, if you select the first item in the collection (index 0), which is a *string*, the issue should be resolved. Here is a simple demonstration:

```sh
class ADGroupTest {
    [string] $Name
    [Collections.ArrayList] $MemberOf = [Collections.ArrayList]::new()

    ADGroupTest ([string] $Name) {
        $this.Name = $Name
    }

    [void] AddMemberOf ([string] $Value) {
        $this.MemberOf.Add($Value)
    }
}

$group = [ADGroupTest] 'MyGroup'
$group.AddMemberOf('hello')

# After instantiating our ADGroupTest object, we see something like this:

# Name    MemberOf
# ----    --------
# MyGroup {hello}

function Get-ADGroupTest {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ADGroupTest] $Identity
    )

    $Identity
}
```

Now if we attempt to use this test function that takes `ADGroupTest` as argument, giving it the collection:

```sh
Get-ADGroupTest $group.MemberOf
```

We would see this error:

> Get-ADGroupTest : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the
> "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "ADGroupTest".

However, if we try the same using the first element in the collection, we can see it has no problem instantiating a new object of the type `ADGroupTest`:

```sh
Get-ADGroupTest $group.MemberOf[0]

Name  MemberOf
----  --------
hello {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The -Identity parameter of Get-ADGroup accepts setting the parameter by pipeline.

Should be able to do this.

```
$group.ForEach( {$_.Memberof | Get-ADGroup -server $DC } )
```

[Answer by Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72209260) - Has a great explanation on why the original code did not work